# Passing a lambda function to DataFrame.apply - what's happening here?

Tags: python, pandas

My question is about the line

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
```

I do understand that this statement converts the dataframe columns to integer values, but was not able to understand the usage of the `lambda` function or the  `errors='coerce'` part.

Comment: To understand error part refer this [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` works on either row- or column-series by applying a function to it. `lambda` is just defining an anonymous function.

For readability, you could define a regular function with better variable names. Consider the following demo:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2'], ['3', 'foo']])
>>> df.dtypes
>>> 
0    object
1    object
dtype: object
```

We have a dataframe full of strings which we want to make numeric. Non-convertible values should be set to `NaN` (this is what `errors='coerce'` does).

```
>>> def make_numeric(series):
...:    return pd.to_numeric(series, errors='coerce')
>>> 
>>> new_df = df.apply(make_numeric)
>>> 
>>> new_df
>>> 
   0    1
0  1  2.0
1  3  NaN
>>> 
>>> new_df.dtypes
>>> 
0      int64
1    float64
dtype: object
```

As you can see, using the `lambda` is just a short way of defining a function. If you don't like it, you can always write a normal function that does the same and is probably more readable.

In this case, defining your own function is a little pointless, because you can just write:

```
>>> df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
>>> 
   0    1
0  1  2.0
1  3  NaN
```

Comment: (Peculiarly, `df.astype` has an `errors` argument, but it can't be `'coerce'`.)